# Connection between variables in Dictionary and other variables in class

Tags: swift, variables, dictionary

In my class I use several variables for calculations, but when I initiate object of this class in Controller, I use dictionaries.

This is the simple code:

```
class MyClass {

  var one: Float = 1.0
  var two: Float = 2.0
  var three: Float = 3.0
  var four: Float = 4.0

  var dictionary = [String: Float]()

  init(type: String) { // Here I use dictionary
    switch type {
      case "type1":
        self.dictionary = ["one": one, "two": two]
      case "type2":
        self.dictionary = ["three": three, "four": four]
      default:
        break
    }
  }

  func calculate() -> Float { // And here I use variables
    return one + two
  }    
}
```

In controller I need dictionaries, because I use keys in `UIPickerView`s and `UITableView`s labels and so on.

But I need to make a strong connection between variables in dictionary and variables in class.

So, when I use in controller:

```
myClass = MyClass(type: "type1")

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  myClass.dictionary["one"] = 1.5 // ["one": 1.5, "two": 2.0]
  print(myClass.one) // 1.0 but I need 1.5
}
```

When I make changes in dictionary, I need to change variables to make further calculations in class with updated variables. Is it possible to make it with declaration of `var`s and `dictionary`? Or I need to write a method, which will update variables each time dictionary will change?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bt is to turn `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` into computed properties, backed by the dictionary. That way, your properties and the dictionary will always be in sync:

```
class MyClass {
    var dictionary = [String: Float]()

    var one: Float {
        get { return self.dictionary["one"]! }
        set { self.dictionary["one"] = newValue }
    }
    var two: Float {
        get { return self.dictionary["two"]! }
        set { self.dictionary["two"] = newValue }
    }
    var three: Float {
        get { return self.dictionary["three"]! }
        set { self.dictionary["three"] = newValue }
    }
    var four: Float {
        get { return self.dictionary["four"]! }
        set { self.dictionary["four"] = newValue }
    }

    init(type: String) {
        switch type {
        case "type1":
            self.dictionary = ["one": 1.0, "two": 2.0]
        case "type2":
            self.dictionary = ["three": 3.0, "four": 4.0]
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func calculate() -> Float {
        return one + two
    }
}

// Usage:
let myClass = MyClass(type: "type1")
myClass.dictionary["one"] = 1.5

print(myClass.one)          // 1.5
print(myClass.calculate())  // 2.0
```

Comment: It would be a lot more readable (and efficient) if you'd use an array instead (`[one, two, three, four]`).